# Remote desktop end point windows azure cloud microsoft

Tags: windows, azure, cloud, virtual-machine

I have a remote desktop account end point with microsoft windows azure.
How do I create another remote desktop account to give my developer to work in the VM ?
I do not want to provide him with my administrator remote desktop account and delete his one or change the password once he is done on his side.
My current one is working and I can remote to my cloud VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with a Hosted Service you could add the following in a startup task, if you use Virtual Machines you can simply execute it on the VM:

```
net user someUser Pa$$w0rd /add
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" someUser /add
```

This adds a new user and adds the user to the Remote Desktop Users, allowing access through RDP.

Comment: Thanks im using a VM. Where do I add these command lines ? cmd promt ?

Comment: Another thing is will microsoft charge me for this new remote desk top user as an endpoint ?

Comment: You simply execute this in the command prompt. You are charged for bandwidth, storage and compute hours, not for endpoints. Take a look at the calculator to get a complete overview of what you can be charged for: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/